# Regular expression for a context free language

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

this is the context free language I've been given:

$S\rightarrow aSTb\\
S\rightarrow b\\
T\rightarrow Ta\\
T\rightarrow \lambda
$

And I want to figure out what language it represents and write the regular expression for it, including conditions that define it. So far I've come up with the following:

$L=\{w\in(aa^*b)^*a^*b| \#_b(w)\leq1+\#_a(w) \}$

where $\#_b(w)$ means the number of b's in the word.

The condition itself seems to be correct, at least for all the examples I tried. However, some words can be created with the expression I wrote but do not belong to the language. For example "aaaaabb"

I'd appreciate any help with this. Thank you

Comment: What is $\lambda$? Is it part of the alphabet or representing the empty string?

Comment: It represents the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression $a^nb(a^{k_1}ba^{k_2}b\ldots a^{k_n}b)^n$ with $n\geq 1$, $k_1,\ldots,k_n\geq 1$.

Comment: You cannot create the word 'b' with that expression, though.

Answer (score 0):

The language has derivations of the form $S\rightarrow aSTb\rightarrow aaSTTb\rightarrow^* a^nST^nb\rightarrow^* a^nba^nb$. All derivations are of this kind. So the language is context-free, but not regular. Use the pumping lemma to show this. Hence, there is no regular expression describing this language.

Comment: Your derivation is incorrect as it can only ever have two $b$s. $S \rightarrow^* a^nb(a^*b)^n$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. The language is still contextfree and not regular due to the two exponents $n$. So my argument is still applicable.

Comment: Indeed, given pumping length $N$, applying the pumping lemma to the string $a^N b^{N + 1}$ shows the language is irregular.

Comment: You are correct, it isn't a regular expression, I apologize for using the wrong terminology. But I'm looking for an expression for the language, regular or not.

Answer (score 0):

The language is indeed context-free and not regular. An expression for it can be obtained by solving the system of equations
\begin{align}
S &= aSTb + b  \\
T &= Ta + 1
\end{align}
The second equation gives immediately $T = a^*$ and thus the first equation becomes $S = aSa^*b + b$. If follows that the language can be written as
$$
L = \bigcup_{n \geqslant 0} a^nb(a^*b)^n
$$

P.S. I use $1$ instead of $\lambda$ for the empty word.